# Setting value of sub-classed float type with magic method

Tags: python, magic-methods

I am trying to implement a bounded float class to learn about magic methods.  So far, I have mostly copied from other Stack Overflow examples and have this:

```
class BoundedFloatError(TypeError, ValueError):
    pass


class BoundedFloat(float):

    def __new__(cls, float_string):
        try: return float.__new__(cls, float_string)
        except (TypeError, ValueError): raise BoundedFloatError(float_string)

    def __init__(self, value, minimum=0.0, maximum=1.0, default=0.5):
        self.minimum = minimum
        self.maximum = maximum
        self.default = default

    def __magic_setter_method__(self, value):    # what is this method?
        if self.minimum <= value <= self.maximum:
            # what goes here?


if __name__ == '__main__':

    y = BoundedFloat(3.14)
    print y, y.minimum, y.maximum, y.default, type(y)
    # 3.14 3.14 1.0 0.5 <class '__main__.BoundedFloat'>

    y = 16.7
    print y, type(y)
    # 16.7 <type 'float'>
```

I am trying to make a new method that sets the value while still keeping the sub-classed float type.  Having searched the documentation on magic methods, I have not found what method is called on setting a float so that I may capture it and enforce bounds.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: When you assign a new value to a variable, the old value plays no part whatsoever in the process.  About the closest thing that would be actually possible to implement would be a BoundedFloatList, which could intercept writes to individual values in the list via ``__setitem__()``.

Comment: But I am just looking for a means to bound the new value when it is assigned. I don't care about the old value.

Comment: Then how are you imagining that the new value is somehow going to be turned into a BoundedFloat?  The only thing around that knows anything about bounds is the old value of the variable, and as I said, that plays no part in the assignment.

Comment: I was hoping that I could find a magic method that would intercept the setting process in much the same way that __setitem__ for a dictionary can capture the setting of an element. If there is no such magic method for floats, then I guess that is a limitation I will just have to live with.